# Running Python Script Again

Tags: python, wxpython

Lets say I have this sample code:

```
import wx

app = wx.App(False)  # Create a new app, don't redirect stdout/stderr to a window.
frame = wx.Frame(None, wx.ID_ANY, "Hello World") # A Frame is a top-level window.
s=wx.Button(frame,-1,"New")
frame.Show(True)     # Show the frame.
app.MainLoop()
```

Like in some programs, if you press the New button, it will open the program again in another window. I am wondering, how can i do this in python?

I cannot make a window object then make copies of it because, in my actual program I am using global variables and these global variables are made for only one window.

It appears that my only option is to find a way to run the program again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try something like this

```
import subprocess
import sys
new_process = subprocess.Popen([sys.executable]+sys.argv)
```

Which will run python again with the arguments it was run with originally.  Or modifying your original example to make pressing the button run the script again :-

```
import wx
import subprocess
import sys

def re_run(e):
    new_process = subprocess.Popen([sys.executable]+sys.argv)

app = wx.App(False)  # Create a new app, don't redirect stdout/stderr to a window.
frame = wx.Frame(None, wx.ID_ANY, "Hello World") # A Frame is a top-level window.
s=wx.Button(frame,-1,"New")
s.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, re_run)
frame.Show(True)     # Show the frame.
app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Actually when I try your example, nothing seems to happen when I click on the button.

Comment: Hmm, Im running on Vista, and I can't see anything happening.

Comment: I got it to work, not a big problem. Also, does this method still work if I convert my program to .exe with py2exe?

Comment: Py2exe: it might do - you'll have to try it!

Comment: Ah this is a really weird computer, Ive tried using py2exe but it ends up crashing the computer, it probably does though (im guessing)